# simple Vue carousel v-for with dinamic index not working with no console errors

Tags: vue.js, slider

I'm trying to build a simple slider with Vue and dinamic data changing based on the selected index but can't get it to work.

Here's the code, I'm pretty sure there is something wrong in the way the index is selected because the looped element is not rendering if I attach the index in sliderTop[sliderIndex], but it renders all the element without it.

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">

    <div class="prev" @click="prev">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
    </div>
    
    <div class="first-image">

        <div class="first-background" v-for="(el) in sliderTop[sliderIndex]" v-if='(el.visible === true)'>

            <div class="first-content">
                <h1>{{el.title}} <span>{{el.specialFont}}</span></h1>
                <p>{{el.paragraph}}</p>
                <button>{{el.button}}</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="next" @click="next">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
    </div>

</div>
```

VUE:

```
sliderIndex: 0,

sliderTop: [
    {
        title: 'Devotion that never',
        specialFont: 'ends',
        paragraph: 'Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi.',
        button: 'READ MORE',
        visible: true,
    },

    {
        title: 'Projects made with',
        specialFont: 'love',
        paragraph: 'Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi.',
        button: 'READ MORE',
        visible: true,
    },
    
    {
        title: 'Our new folio full of',
        specialFont: 'joy',
        paragraph: 'Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi.',
        button: 'READ MORE',
        visible: true,
    }
],

next: function (){
    if (this.sliderIndex < 2) {
        this.sliderIndex += 1;
    } else {
        this.sliderIndex = 0;
    }
},

prev: function (){
    if (this.sliderIndex > 0) {
        this.sliderIndex -= 1;
    } else {
        this.sliderIndex = 2;
    }
},
```

Comment: Add a key with `:key="sliderIndex"` with v-for loop, so whenever the sliderIndex is changed the component will be re-rendered

Comment: Hey , I tried that but still, if I have [sliderIndex] attached to sliderTop it doesn't show anything, if I remove [sliderIndex] it shows all the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to make a slider as you mentioned, you need to create a v-for for sliderTop array. Currently, you have only one slide.
2. You used v-for and v-if in the same div, which is not allowed.
3. When you use v-for with object (sliderTop[sliderIndex] is an object) "el" becomes the value. For example, in the first iteration, el is "Devotion that never", in the second iteration, it is "ends", etc.

```js
<div class="slider">
   // prev button
   <div
       :class="['slide', `slide-${index}`, index == sliderIndex ? 'active' : '']"
       v-for="(slide, index) in sliderTop"
       :key="index"
   >
      <h1>{{slide.title}}
      <span>{{slide.specialFont}}</span></h1>
      <p>{{slide.paragraph}}</p>
      <button>{{slide.button}}</button>
   </div>
   // next button
</div>
```

After that, you need to change sliderIndex by prev/next buttons and change the visibility in CSS based on active class.

For example

```
.slider {
   position: relative
}
.slide {
   position: absolute
   top:0
   left:0
   right:0
   bottom:0
   opacity:0
   transform: translateX(-100%)
   transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out
}
.slide.active {
   opacity:1
   transform: translateX(0)
}
```